# From the profit tables I need to filter only the negative profit values using pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the profit tables I need to filter only the negative profit values.

Input:

```
Title        Profit
Zootopia    191268248
T-Men       -13594629
S-Men       33914986
```

Output:

```
Title        Profit
T-Men       -13594629
```

Logics:
Implement using python pandas Dataframe

Wrong code:

```
movies['Profit'] .sort_values(ascending=True)
movies[["Title","Profit"]]
```

Suggest me to get the right logics.

Thanks, SBFL

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort the dataframe in the above code. Instead use this:

`new_movies = movies[movies['Profit'] < 0]`

Comment: After the above logics output is not displayed as expected.  The  Profit should be displayed -13594629 but it display as NAN